# Reading tuples in a devicetree

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I am trying to find a way to use tuples in a device tree and read it from a driver.

Example:

```dts
property = <"str1" 0x01>, <"str2" 0x45>, <"str3", 0x60>, ...
```

I want to read the strings "str1", "str2" with their respective values i.e. 0x01 and 0x45.

Could you guys help me in confirming that this is possible? And how can I read these from my driver.

Comment: You can't do that. The properties have type besides them, mixing strings and numbers is now allowed as far as I can tell. It' possible to enconde strings up to 8 bytes into numbers though. But it's very hackish way to achieve what you want.

Comment: You cannot do that because the strings cannot be inside angle brackets. You could do `property = "str1", <0x01>, "str2", <0x45>, "str3, <0x60>, ...;`, but your code would have to parse the property itself because it is not a standard format. It would be simpler to split the property into two properties: one containing the string list and one containing the number list.

Comment: If you split the strings out to a separate string list property, e.g. `property-names = "str1", "str2", "str3", ...;`, there are a number of functions that operate of string lists, such as `of_property_count_strings()` (count number of strings in list), `of_property_read_string_index()` (copy a string from an index in a string list), `of_property_read_string_array()` (get array of pointers to strings in a string list), `of_property_match_string()` (search a string list for a given string and return its index).